# How do I get an object from a list where a property of that object matches a certain value?

Tags: c#, list, object, search, properties

Say I have a class `Person` which has a property `PersonId` of type `int`, and a class `Company` which has a property `Persons` of type `List<Person>`. I also have a `Company` object called `company1`. The code for this would be as follows:

```
class Company
{
    public List<Person> Persons { get; private set; }

    public Company()
    {
        this.Persons = new List<Person>();
    }
}

class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}

// In a different class
public static Company company1 = new Company();
```

I need to return the `Person` object in the `Persons` list whose property `PersonId` matches a certain value, given by `selectedPersonId`.

Here is the code I'd currently use to do this:

```
Person person1;
int personIndex = company1.FindPersonIndexById(selectedPersonId);
if (personIndex != -1)
{
    person1 = company1.Persons[personIndex];
}
```

where `FindPersonIndexById(int)` is a method in the `Company` class:

```
public int FindPersonIndexById(int personId)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Persons.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (Persons[i].PersonId == personId)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Is this the best way of getting an object from a list where a property of that object matches a certain value, or is there a better or more concise way of doing this?**
I'm not sure if this is similar to this question: [Check whether a List of object has a node which matches a given property of that object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619920/check-whether-a-list-of-object-has-a-node-which-matches-a-given-property-of-that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is using `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
Person person1 = Persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PersonId = selectedPersonId);
```

This (as [Mihai Carcostea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2321874/mihai-caracostea) pointed out) requires the addition of a `using System.Linq`.

**Note**: `person1` will be `null` if no person in the list is found with the specified ID.

Comment: `Where` would return a _collection_ of objects.  I think you want `First` or `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Comment: For this problem you do not want to use `FirstOrDefault`

In this use case we are searching for only a single row of data from the database based on the primary key, if you use `SingleOrDefault` you are specifying that only one row should be returned, yet if anymore rows return (major data error) it will throw an exception. 

However if you use `FirstOrDefault`, it may find 2 rows (which again, is a data error), however it will just return the first row with no exception.

Answer (score 3):

I would use Linq to do that job:

```
var personIWantToFind = Persons.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PersonId == personId);
```

Answer (score 1):

More concise would be:

```
Person person = company1.Persons.Where(p=>p.PersonId == myValue).FirstOrDefault();
```

This requires a `using System.Linq;` directive

EDIT: Thank you, D Stanley

Comment: Your use of `var` hides the fact that `Where` returns a _collection_ of objects, not a _single_ object like the OP is wanting.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the person with that id is not found, null will be returned